# Background color only filling h2 element not its entire div container

Tags: html, css

I have the following div and h2 element below. I'm trying to fill the entire div with a blue color, but instead of filling the entire container2 class like I expect it only fills the h2 section. Why is it doing this and how can I fill the entire container2 section (which has some margin and padding outside the area of the h2?

```css
    h2 {
      color: white;
      font-size: 35px;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .container2 {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Carnas-Light;
      background-color: #0f2c4d;
      margin-top: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      width: 83.33333333%;
      margin-left: 8.33333333%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container2">
                        <h2>WorkWave provides intuitive cloud-based field service & fleet management solutions that help organizations with a mobile workforce transform their business.</h2>
                </div>
```

Comment: It's filling whole container2. Check Chrome Dev Tools. It will not apply background to margins.

Comment: how do you get it to apply the color to the margins then?

Comment: There's no way to do that. Replace margin with padding.

Comment: add `overflow: auto;` to container ... you are facing margin collapsing issue, the margin of h2 is getting outside

Comment: and in case you want to fill the whole screen, remove all the margin, or add background to body

Answer (score 0):

Just add the next style code into your stylesheet:

```
.container2 > h2 {
  background-color: #0f2c4d;
}
```

Your way does not work, because you set **BG-color** only for parent element `container2`, instead of using the inheriting and  for `h2` elem.

Run the code:

```css
    h2 {
      color: white;
      font-size: 35px;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .container2 {
     text-align: center;
     font-family: Carnas-Light;
     background-color: #0f2c4d;
     padding-top: 40px;
     padding-bottom: 40px;
     padding-right: 15px;
     padding-left: 15px;
     width: 83.33333333%;
     margin-left: 8.33333333%;
     height: 100%;
    }

    .container2 > h2 {
      background-color: #0f2c4d;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Title</title>

  <style>


  </style>

</head>
<body>
 
 <div style="background-color: #0f2c4d;">
  <div class="container2">
            <h2>WorkWave provides intuitive cloud-based field service &amp; fleet management solutions that help organizations with a mobile workforce transform their business.</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: Oh, maybe we have the misunderstanding. You need to change your margins to padding. And also put your container2 into the support <div>. So try this:

`.container2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Carnas-Light;
    background-color: #0f2c4d;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 83.33333333%;
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
    height: 100%;
}`

Comment: with this: 

`<div style="
    background-color: #0f2c4d;
"><div class="container2">
                        <h2>WorkWave provides intuitive cloud-based field service &amp; fleet management solutions that help organizations with a mobile workforce transform their business.</h2>
                </div></div>` @Dog let me know, please, if this was help you

Comment: thanks, i got it. it was those margins causing issues.

Comment: @Dog I'm glad that help you. Please, mark my answer as correct to your question, if it was helpful you! )

Comment: it's helpful but not entirely correct because it doesn't account for the side margins, but i hooked you up with an up vote.

Comment: @Dog margins never have a `background-color` setup. You can set it only to paddings. If you really need to do this for margins you should describe your question more. Because to do this we have a several ways with different methods.